# Azure search - $skip in PHP

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, azure-cognitive-search

Let's say I have this code in PHP:

```
public function getFromAzure($searchParam, $jobCategory, $top, $skip, $request){
    $listingManager = $this->get('rd.model_manager.job_listing');
    $url = $listingManager->getAzureSearchParam($request, 'azure_search_idx');
    $apiKey = $listingManager->getAzureSearchParam($request, 'azure_key');

    $searchParam = preg_replace('/\s+/', '+', $searchParam);
    $postdata = json_encode(
        array(
            'search' => $searchParam,
            'filter' => $category,
            'orderby'=> 'publishedDate desc',
            'facets' => array('locationName','employmentType', 'workSchedule','jobFunction','positionLevel','industry'),
            'top' => $top,
            'skip' => $skip,
            'count' => true
            )
    );    



    $opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"POST",
        'header'=>"Content-type: application/json\r\n" .
                  "api-key: ". $apiKey . "\r\n" .
                  "Accept: application/json",
        'content'=>$postdata
      )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);

    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $file = json_decode($file,true);
    return $file;

}
```

Is there a way I can iterate the $skip inside this function(PHP)?
Currently I am iterating skip through Ajax call from javascript. 1 ajax call per (15 record) skip.

I need to iterate the skip because I need to load about 2,000 records(and counting)on page load, which per query is limited to 1,000. and assuming if I have 10,000 records or more. then I would have to run ajax every 1000 (for example) which could have performance issue.

btw fyi only- I need this on facets. where I have to iterate throught all records and get their value of my facet categories.

Thank you in advance! Cheers!

Comment: To clarify -- Are you reading all the documents just so you can get all the unique values of the facetable fields? Or am I misunderstanding your goal?

Comment: Yes I am reading through all documents to get the values. Is there a shorter way, or azure search has way to get just all unique values, and possibly count it at the same time?

Comment: Sorry, one more question -- Since you're including a filter and search text in the request, is it safe to assume you're trying to exclude facets that don't match those criteria?